# How to set JavaScript exception breakage in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

If I remember correctly, Visual Studio was not breaking on unhanded JavaScript exceptions sometime ago. And now I see the following which helped me to find the problem very quickly. So my question is what is the setting necessary for Visual Studio to break and show the necessary information(as shown in the figure) when a JavaScript exceptions occur.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you debug your code using Internet Explorer. Your screenshot shows you are running your code in iexplore.exe.

You can refer to this msdn article for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx

From the article:
"Visual Studio provides enhanced error messages for common script debugging problems. These messages do not appear unless you attach to Internet Explorer manually. If you encounter an error condition when Internet Explorer is opened automatically, try manually attaching so that you can see the error messages."

Comment: So you mean no additional settings are needed?

Comment: You do have to attach manually to Internet Explorer in order to get the enhanced error messaging. Let me include that in my answer.